# What is the name of the 'corner swipe' to change motion animations on the Apple Watch?

Tags: apple-watch, watchos

I've got the jellyfish motion animation on the face of my Apple watch. This has multiple different jelly fish.

I've found I can jump to the next jelly fish by doing a 'corner swipe'. This is swiping along the top left hand corner of the watch.

I've never heard of a 'corner swipe' idiom. Does anybody have any information on it? I need to know the 'name' in order to find out more.

My question is: **What is the name of the 'corner swipe' to change motion animations on the Apple Watch?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell, what makes the watch face advance to the next jellyfish is a **tap**. Your "corner swipe" must be just along the sensor in a way that it looks to the device like a tap.